# ssh session hanging with vagrant virtualbox

Tags: ssh, vagrant, virtualbox

I've been using Virtualbox + Vagrant to spin up an ubuntu vm on my mac to use as a space to play and mess around with various programs tools etc..

I have mounted a directory in my Vagrant file like so..

```
config.vm.synced_folder "~/projects", "/vagrant/projects"
```

in almost every ssh session or every 2nd session . after a while of being in this directory and doing some basic terminal commands.. eg cd , making . deleting files etc, my session just hangs and I need to send the terminal kill command or close the terminal window and reconnect..

I just accepted this behaviour as a quirk of the software but I'd like to know more about why its happening.. I'm not sure where to look for clues, but I was wondering if other people had similar issues ? Know the cause or know the fix?

My suspicions is something to do with the way it does dir syncing? But again I don't know how to confirm.

Would it be better to just not mount a shared folder and use the vm's filesystem instead?

Answer (score 0):

We've found much better Vagrant reliability between Mac hosts and Ubuntu guests when using NFS-based shared folders. Here's a config that will work in your Vagrantfile to get you started. You don't need any special plugin on the guest or host side.

```
folder_mount_options = {
  :type => "nfs",
  :mount_options => ['noatime', 'vers=3', 'proto=udp', 'actimeo=2']
}

config.vm.synced_folder '~/projects', '/vagrant/projects', folder_mount_options
```

One limitation of NFS that you might need to be aware of is that you can't share a parent folder and a subfolder as separate mount points, but that's not too big of a deal. For example, you couldn't share `~/projects` as `/vagrant/projects` as well as `~/projects/specialproject` at `/var/www`

Finally, if you want to try to dig into what's happening when things do freeze, try running `dmesg` inside of your vagrant box, or look at `Console.app` (you can find it with Spotlight) in your Mac. You might find some clues there.

Good luck!